# Laying out images in Word document programmatically

Tags: wpf, ms-word, vsto, office-interop

I'm trying to generate a Word document through my application coded in WPF. In that document, I also need to layout few images along with caption as shown in the image below.

[image]

All the images are stored in database as base64 string. I'm able to load the images as "BitmapImage" object in the document however not sure how to layout the images as shown in image. Code snippet to load the images in document is as below :

```
        var bookmarks = wordDoc.Bookmarks;
        var range = bookmarks["ExternalImage"].Range;
        foreach (var image in ExternalImages) // here image is "BitmapImage" object
        {
            float scaleHeight = (float)250 / (float)image.Image.PixelHeight;
            float scaleWidth = (float)250 / (float)image.Image.PixelWidth;
            var min = Math.Min(scaleHeight, scaleWidth);
            var bitmap = new TransformedBitmap(image, new ScaleTransform(min, min));   
            System.Windows.Clipboard.SetImage(bitmap);
            range.Paste();
        }
```

How can I lay out the images as shown in image above along with caption? Note that I'm not loading images from file but from memory object.

Comment: You first need to explore Word as a user, in order to explore laying out the graphics + captions. I can give you a few tips, in a comment, but any discussion should be carried out in Super User or Microsoft Answers. My first thought would be to create a three-row, two-column table and merge the cells in the second row. Insert the images as InlineShapes, the captions in a second paragraph in the cell. Paragraph alignment "centered".

Comment: @CindyMeister If I'm not wrong then Inlineshapes doesn't support inserting of images as Bitmap objects. It only supports adding image from file objects so I got stuck with it

Comment: A Shape can be converted to an InlineShape (`Shape.ConvertToInlineShape` method)...

Comment: @CindyMeister based on your suggestion, I have put the code snippet to achieve the desired result. Thanks for pointing the direction

Comment: You're welcome. I see possibilities to make your code more efficient. Do you want me to edit your Answer or post it as a new Answer?

Comment: you can edit the answer and suggest the improvements. Thanks

Comment: code edited :-)

Answer (score 1):

Based on the direction provided by @CindyMeister in comments, following is the working code snippet to layout the images using code :

```
    imageTable = wordDoc.Tables.Add(sel.Range, rows, cols, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);
    imageTable.AllowAutoFit = true;
    row = 1; col = 1;
    foreach (var image in Images)
   {
      float scaleHeight = (float)475 / (float)image.PixelHeight;   
     // here 475 is approx image size I want in word document
     float scaleWidth = (float)475 / (float)image.PixelWidth;
     var min = Math.Min(scaleHeight, scaleWidth);

     var bitmap = new TransformedBitmap(image, new ScaleTransform(min, min));

     System.Windows.Clipboard.SetImage(bitmap);

     //more efficient/faster in C# if you don't "drill down" multiple times to get an object
     Word.Cell cel = imageTable.Cell(row, col);
     Word.Range rngCell = cel.Range;
     Word.Range rngTable = imageTable.Range;

     rngCell.Paste();
     cel.VerticalAlignment = WdCellVerticalAlignment.wdCellAlignVerticalCenter;
     rngCell.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = WdParagraphAlignment.wdAlignParagraphCenter; 
     // set caption below image
     rngTable.ParagraphFormat.SpaceAfter = 6;
     rngCell.InsertAfter(image.Caption);
     rngTable.Font.Name = "Arial Bold";
     row++;
  }
```

This code I have posted for reference, only, to let people have some starting point. Any suggestions welcome.